# Embeddinator-4000 : Xamarin mvvmcross sub apps into native iOS app in objective-C

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, embeddinator

i have a question about embeddinator-4000. I will provide you with a bit of background :

We are currently trying to embedd some of our xamarin apps into a native objective-c app container. For this, i have created a poc in which i instantiate and call a Xamarin navigation controller into the native app. The navigation is managed by the xamarin subapp, and it seems to work fine. The problem is that we use MvvmCross inside our Xamarin apps for navigation, bindings etc...

My question is : are we able to instantiate Mvvmcross in the nativ app container in order to use Mvvmcross in my subapps ?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @Cheesebaron In fact, i'm looking for the right way/procedure to do the mvvmcross initialization. I'm currently trying to modify the native objective C AppDelegate class and calling the "CreateApplication()" method from my embedd Xamarin app.

Comment: @Cheesebaron When i embedd my code, i have errors like : error EM009 : The feature 'Converting type MvvmCross.Navigation.IMvxNavigationService to mono code' is not currently supported by the tool.